# Unable to connect to EC2 instance via ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

I'm having trouble connecting my EC2 instance via ssh. Currently my session times out when I try to connect.

I have a security group with the following settings

Inbound:

```
Type: All traffic
Protocol: All
Port Range: All
Source: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Outbound:

```
Type: All traffic
Protocol: All
Port Range: All
Destination: 0.0.0.0/0
```

I followed the instructions on saving the private key and converting it to use with putty. When I put the public dns into putty, I am unable to connect. I verified the host name resolves by an online DNS checker.

On the client side, I launch putty and put the following information in:

```
Host name (or IP address): ec2-user@<Public DNS value>
Port: 22
Connection Type: ssh
```

In the connection->ssh->Auth->Private Key File for Authentication I point it to my private key from AWS after it has been transformed to a ppk.

Is there anything else I need to setup to be able to connect to the EC2 instance?

Comment: Mention the commands/setting you use to connect as well.

Comment: @SanchitAnand will do.

Comment: what is your AMI Instance type? If it is anything other than amazon default AMI, you may need to change the host name from ec2-user to something else.

Comment: @SanchitAnand AMI instance type is Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4 (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-26ebbc5c.

Comment: Are you on the default VPC? If not try it on the default VPC first. If you are using the DNS name, try the public IP address first. Finally check your firewall settings if you have one.

Comment: @SanchitAnand I'm using the default VPC. I'm also not running a firewall.

Comment: @lordoku check if your ec2 is in a public subnet, and your network ACL too, it might block the incoming SSH traffic.

Comment: @Victor how can I tell if it's in a public subnet? Where are the settings for the network ACL?

Comment: @lordoku go to VPC -> Subnets and find your subnet (subnet ID is in ec2 instance Description). On the Route Table tab find what's the Target for 0.0.0.0/0 Destination. If it looks like igw-ab2a5re8 then you have a public subnet. Then check on Network ACL tab if all traffic is allowed from  
0.0.0.0/0 source.

Comment: @Victor The value for the route table target is igw-########. So it looks like I have a public subnet. For the network ACL I have a rule that says All traffic all: 0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW. There's also a rule with * for the rule number that  has traffic all: 0.0.0.0/0  DENY.

Comment: Standard toubleshooting: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html

Comment: @lordoku try to telnet port 22 to your instance:
telnet <instance IP> 22

If you're working on Windows, you can try to use Moba Xterm for that. It's a free CLI terminal.

Comment: @Victor I was able to lookup the host name with a simple Java application that first looks up the first name and then tries to connect to it with a socket. The host resolved, so it looks like DNS is working, it seems like the port is blocked somewhere or isn't configured correctly. I'm not sure where else to look.

Comment: @lordoku a telnet command would tell exactly if there's network access to the instance. I'd even use the public IP of the instance for troubleshooting.

Comment: @Victor I tried using telenet from putty and am still getting connection timed out. It's behaving as though the ports aren't open. I've tried from my home network and my work network and am getting the same result.

Comment: @lordoku can you check again if your instance is in that subnet? Subnet ID is displayed in instance Description tab. And if it matches, please list what you have in that subnet Routing Table.

Comment: @Victor I just heard back from AWS tech support. Apparently my settings were correct, but my account was set to isolated. I'm going to go ahead and answer this question. Thanks for all of your help, I had fun troubleshooting with you.

Comment: @lordoku Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with the account and not a technical issue. For whatever reason my account was set to isolated mode by Amazon. The AWS tech support verified that all of the settings were correct.